# How to Identify React Styled Components in DOM?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm using Styled Components in React and I can create a component like so:

```
export const Screen = styled.div({
  display: "flex",
});
```

I then include it in my render code like this:

```
<Screen>...</Screen>
```

(where the `...` above just represents other components).

However, when I look at the DOM, I have a hard time identifying my styled components from each other because their class names are just random strings: e.g. `class="css-k008qs"`.

Is there any way to give the style components a name that will be seen in the DOM either in addition to or instead of the randomly generated class name?

Comment: you can also set a `className` to your `styled component` for example `<Screen className="screen-component-className">...</Screen> `

Comment: @OmarDieh I thought I had tried that before, but maybe not. Regardless, yours worked! Could you post it as an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: Hi @Elliptica :) I have already posted it as an answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also give a `className` to your `styled` component.
you can achieve that by :

- **solution A** *on component render*
  pass the `className` inside the components `attributes`

```
<Screen className="screen-component-className">...</Screen>
```

- **solution B** *on component initiation*
  add `.attrs` after your `styled.div` pass the `className` inside the components `attributes`

```
const Screen = styled.div.attrs({
  className: "screen-component-className"
})({
  display: "flex"
});
```

both methods will set a `className` to your `styled components` :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `babel-plugin-styled-components` for this. Please follow this guide: https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin

Another way could be to write your own wrapper for `styled()`. But you have to manually use it in a lot of places unless you want to fork Styled Components.

Without touching Styled Components lib, you may try:

```js
function prefixComponentName(Component, prefix) {
   Component.displayName = prefix + Component.displayName ?? Component.name;
   return Component;
}
```

Then use it wherever you need it, e.g.

```js
export const Screen = prefixComponentName(styled.div({
  display: "flex",
}), "Styled");
```

But IMO, babel plugin is the best if it suits you.